# fastest way convert tab-delimited file to csv in linux

Tags: linux, csv

I have a tab-delimited file that has over 200 million lines.  What's the fastest way in linux to convert this to a csv file?  This file does have multiple lines of header information which I'll need to strip out down the road, but the number of lines of header is known.  I have seen suggestions for `sed` and `gawk`, but I wonder if there is a "preferred" choice.

Just to clarify, there are no embedded tabs in this file.

Comment: For csv to tsv and embedded delimiter issues, see also answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475535/replace-every-comma-not-enclosed-in-a-pair-of-double-quotes-with (also relevant : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/remove-comma-between-the-quotes-only-in-a-comma-delimited-file).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If all you need to do is *translate* all tab characters to comma characters, `tr` is probably the way to go.

The blank space here is a literal tab:

```
$ echo "hello   world" | tr "\\t" ","
hello,world
```

Of course, if you have embedded tabs inside string literals in the file, this will incorrectly translate those as well; but embedded literal tabs would be fairly uncommon.

Comment: More common are embedded commas in the source, which then require wrapping with quotes. Which is troublesome if there are embedded quotes...

Comment: Thanks for the `tr` suggestion.  How does it compare to `sed` with speed?  Suppose you wanted to skip the header start at line number x and continue to the rest of the file.  Is there a way to implement this with `tr`?  (I should also clarify that there are no embedded commas in the file.)

Comment: @andrewj: `tr` should be much faster, as it's just doing character-by-character replacement instead of regex matching. As for skipping header, the easiest thing is to just process in two chunks - if you know the length, `head -n <length> input > output; tail -n +<length+1> input | tr ... >> output`; if you don't know the length, probably something with `grep -n`...

Comment: @andrew, sed has support for transliteration, also you can use address range.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer; `"` must be converted into `""` for CSV, fields must be wrapped in `"` quotes if they contain quotes or commas or newlines (though newlines will not exist in data presented as TSV).

Answer (score 86):

If you're worried about embedded commas then you'll need to use a slightly more intelligent method. Here's a Python script that takes TSV lines from stdin and writes CSV lines to stdout:

```
import sys
import csv

tabin = csv.reader(sys.stdin, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
commaout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect=csv.excel)
for row in tabin:
  commaout.writerow(row)
```

Run it from a shell as follows:

```
python script.py < input.tsv > output.csv
```

Comment: Unless you know for sure that there are no embedded commas and no embedded tabs, this is a very reliable way to do it.  Even though it probably doesn't meet the criteria for being 'the fastest'.

Comment: It may not be "the fastest" , but it does handles embedded tabs and commas for me.

Comment: This rocks.  I was writing a cryptic sed script to take care of this in bash - but that can't compete with the completeness of the python csv library.  Thank you Ignacio, for this offering.  Regarding speed - Ease of use use and reliability way outway speed - this is certainly fast enough.  :-)

Comment: Ignacio, with your permission I'd like to add your script, with attribution, as tab2csv in my [vbin](http://crowfly.net/vbin) library.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks, Ignacio.  [vbin/t2c](http://crowfly.net/vbin/#t2cHelp)

Comment: Excel 2010 didn't like this tsv->csv conversion for at least one of my .tsv files until specifically quoting all the fields: `commaout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect=csv.excel, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`. Possibly due to my tsv not being "properly" quoted for Excel?

Comment: Indeed, to me that was the best choice! Other options might fail whenever there were tabs or commas inside the file. This Python library is a flexible yet seamless solution!

Comment: If you're doing this in windows and getting extra lines between each row try adding `lineterminator='\n'` to the commaout line:


```commaout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n', dialect=csv.excel)```

Answer (score 22):

```
perl -lpe 's/"/""/g; s/^|$/"/g; s/\t/","/g' < input.tab > output.csv
```

Perl is generally faster at this sort of thing than the sed, awk, and Python.

Comment: best answer for me, only one slightly change, scape double quotes: perl -lpe 's/"/\\"/g; s/^|$/"/g; s/\t/","/g' < ...

Comment: long live Perl! Exactly the one-liner that I needed.

Comment: You're a saviour

Comment: dope, have not used this language in years, perfect and fast!

Answer (score 13):

- If you want to convert the whole tsv file into a csv file:

  ```
  $ cat data.tsv | tr "\\t" "," > data.csv
  ```

  ---
- If you want to omit some fields:

  ```
  $ cat data.tsv | cut -f1,2,3 | tr "\\t" "," > data.csv
  ```

  The above command will convert the data.tsv file to data.csv file ***containing only the first three*** fields.

Answer (score 8):

```
sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/<tab>/","/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' infile > outfile
```

Damn the critics, quote everything, CSV doesn't care.

`<tab>` is the actual tab character. \t didn't work for me. In bash, use ^V to enter it.

Comment: For tab, you can do `sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e "s/\t/\",\"/g" -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' infile > outfile`.

Answer (score 7):

@ignacio-vazquez-abrams 's python solution is great! For people who are looking to parse delimiters other tab, the library actually allows you to set arbitrary delimiter. Here is my modified version to handle pipe-delimited files:

```
import sys
import csv

pipein = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter='|')
commaout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect=csv.excel)
for row in pipein:
  commaout.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 4):

assuming you don't want to change header and assuming you don't have embedded tabs

```
# cat file
header  header  header
one     two     three

$ awk 'NR>1{$1=$1}1' OFS="," file
header  header  header
one,two,three
```

NR>1 skips the first header. you mentioned you know how many lines of header, so use the correct number for your own case. with this, you also do not need to call any other external commands. just one awk command does the job.

another way if you have blank columns and you care about that.

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub("\t",",")}1' file
```

using sed

```
sed '2,$y/\t/,/' file #skip 1 line header and translate (same as tr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) for this

```
xsv input -d '\t' input.tsv > output.csv
```

In my test on a 300MB tsv file, it was roughly 5x faster than the python solution (2.5s vs. 14s).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting **xsv**. I've been looking at a fast CSV toolkit for a while.

Answer (score 0):

the following awk oneliner supports quoting + quote-escaping

```
printf "flop\tflap\"" | awk -F '\t' '{ gsub(/"/,"\"\"\"",$i); for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf "\"%s\"",$i; if( i < NF ) printf "," }; printf "\n" }'
```

gives

```
"flop","flap""""
```

Answer (score 0):

right click file, click rename, delete the 't' and put a 'c'. I'm actually not joking, most csv parsers can handle tab delimiters. I had this issue now and for my purposes renaming worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better not to cat the file because it may create problem in the case of large file. The better way may be

`$ tr ',' '\t' < csvfile.csv > tabdelimitedFile.txt`

The command will get input from csvfile.csv and store the result as tab seperated in tabdelimitedFile.txt