# MySQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE to a different server?

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I have a shell script on server a. The script spits out a csv file to a local directory. The problem is the database server is on server b. How do I use **select * into outfile** in a setup like this?

I get

```
Can't create/write to file '/home/username/test.csv/' (Errcode: 2)
```

Solved load data infile by using 'LOCAL' keyword. Is there something like that for outfile?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`select into outfile` can only create the file on the server, not the client.

Here's what the manual recommends for your situation:

> If you want to create the resulting
>   file on some client host other than
>   the server host, you cannot use SELECT
>   ... INTO OUTFILE. In that case, you
>   should instead use a command such as
>   mysql -e "SELECT ..." >  file_name to
>   generate the file on the client host.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: Any chance they will be implementing the LOCAL keyword into outfile like they do with infile in the next release? This simple issue is causing a great deal of extra work.. Thank you!

Comment: I doubt it. Have you tried the recommended approach using `mysql -e` and redirecting the output to a local file?

Comment: Since it was dumping it as text and there is no way of dumping it as csv file, I had to ignore this approach altogether. MySQL is making it really difficult to perform such a simple task :( Thanks again!

Comment: Well, you can dump the results to a local tab-delimited file using `mysql -B -e` and then convert it to CSV. Here are some tips on doing the conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535255/fastest-way-convert-tab-delimited-file-to-csv-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

Use the command below:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -h DBIP DBNAME -e \
"SELECT * FROM tablename" > /destinationpath/outputfilename.csv
```

Comment: not working....