# Exporting .csv data locally from a distant MySQL server

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a MySQL server running on one PC (WinXP).

On another PC (WinXP), I'd like to backup tables to [csv](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files so I have a c++ program connect to the MySQL database and then I issue a command like this:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE something=ABC
INTO OUTFILE c\tmp.txt
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ";";
```

the data seems to get exported but on the Servers "c:\" not on my PC:s "c:\".
I can't just fetch the data over the LAN either as my program is running as a windows service.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804332/mysql-select-into-outfile-to-a-different-server) but it seems I can't use "FIELDS TERMINATED BY" etc. with that solution.

Can I export csv data locally from a distant server or do I have to migrate the data locally first?

Problem "solved" : As it seems you can't do it in a 'simple' way, I run the service on the PC with MySQL and have a DCom server periodically move the data to the other PC.

Comment: why not back up with mysqldump? why csvs? dumps are just for what you want. Also, this would be much much easier to do in a rich scripting language like python than with C++.

Comment: I already do that (mysqldump-ing) and it works fine but I also need a "human readable" version. For the python question, I don't have access to scripting languages and I must implement the program as a windows service.

Comment: Yeah and the best comes the day the company will start to blend in Windows Seven in it all...

Comment: actually there's probably a nice CSV engine in .net, maybe just write the dumper yourself and get it over with?

Comment: .net is a no goer too, only c++ (and VB6 actually, *shrugs*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Intended to be a comment (but I don't have enough rep points to comment).***  Not sure if you are able to install things, but you could try using **cygwin + sqsh** (http://www.sqsh.org/sqsh_home.html).  I'm a linux user and sqsh is a great tool for grabbing data from databases.

Comment: Well, I definitely can't install cygwin but even if sqsh can work without it, would it solve my problem and if so how? ps. +1 towards commenting ;-)

Comment: @Valmond  thx for the +1.  Unfortunately, I'm Not aware of a way for you to run sqsh without cygwin :-( and you would have to do some additional formatting of the output to get it into the csv format you desire. Have you seen: http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/using-a-mysql-databases-with-c-a70097 might be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE obviously writes the file on the local filesystem of the mysql-demon. One option might be to share a directory of your client-PC, open it on your server and use its path for the outfile-option. If this is not an option you might have to select the data in your c++ program and write it (kind of manually) to a local csv-file.

Comment: As you say, I can't do it that way (a service can only write locally).

Answer (score 0):

use the following command, if you don't want to install extra.

```
mysql -h remotedb.db -u ident -p -B -e "your query ;" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > localfile.csv
```

-B means make the output as tab separated.