# Replace every comma not enclosed in a pair of double quotes with '|'

Tags: sed, awk

I want to replace every comma not enclosed in a pair of double quotes with '|' using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) pattern matching within [sed](/questions/tagged/sed).

For example, given the following input:

```
A,B,"C,D",E,"F,G",H,"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen",33,MIS,"Taiwan, Taipei",M
```

This is the desired output:

```
A|B|"C,D"|E|"F,G"|H|"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M
```

I want this accomplished without using hard coding like:

```
sed '2s/33,MIS/33|MIS|/' file.
```

Comment: "Could you please do my homework?" - Just kidding, what did you try so far?

Comment: [A similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48672/17666) was asked on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It sounds like you're running away from the problem of writing a CSV file read function. Replacing commas with pipes will only work if there are no pipe characters already in the file! Google CSV-1203 for a CSV spec with hairs on its chest ;o)

Comment: @thor the question you point ask precisely the invers operation as whiping commas **IN** quoted strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First sample: Quick and dirty:

If your comma are ALWAY followed by a space in text strings, and NEVER in field separation, you could use:

```
sed -e 's/,\([^ ]\)/\|\1/g'
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M
```

but you have to be *sure* about *next character*.

More elaborated sample, whithout need of space, closest to your original idea.

```
sed -e ':a;s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|[^",]*\)*\),/\1|/;ta'

echo '"Chang, Yao-Jen",33,MIS,"Taiwan, Taipei",M' |
  sed -e ':a;s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|[^",]*\)*\),/\1|/;ta'
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M

echo '"Chang,Yao-Jen",33,MIS,"Taiwan,Taipei",M' |
  sed -e '1 { :a;s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|[^",]*\)*\),/\1|/;ta }'
"Chang,Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan,Taipei"|M
```

Explained:

```
sed -e '
    :a
    s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|[^",]*\)*\),/\1|/
    ta
'
```

- `:a` is a address location for branch (loop)
- `s/` search from begin of line for '[^",]*,' or '"...",' than replace comma by vbar.
- `ta` branch to a if previous `s/` have been matched.

As you requested to operate on *line 2*, you will have to:

```
sed -e '2 { :a; s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|[^",]*\)*\),/\1|/; ta } '
```

**Edited:** [WRONG! See *Edit 3*]

Another sample if you wanna have mixed quotes and double-quotes:

There is a sample with mixed quoted, non-quoted, and one field
**containing a quote, but double quoted**:

```
cat <<eof >sample
A,B,"C,D",E,"F,G",H,"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen",33,MIS,"Taiwan, Taipei",M
A,B,'C,D',E,'F,G',H,'I,J,K'
'Chang, Yao-Jen',33,MIS,'Taiwan, Taipei',M
"Chang, Yao-Jen",33,MIS,"Taiwan, Taipei",M,'Chang,Yao-Jen',34,MZZ,'Taiwan, Taipei',Z
"Chang's son: Yao-Lu",55,MAA,'Taiwan, too',z
eof

sed -e ':a;s/^\(\(\(['\''"]\)[^\3]*\3\|[^",'\'']*\)*\),/\1|/;ta' sample
A|B|"C,D"|E|"F,G"|H|"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M
A|B|'C,D'|E|'F,G'|H|'I,J,K'
'Chang, Yao-Jen'|33|MIS|'Taiwan, Taipei'|M
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M|'Chang,Yao-Jen'|34|MZZ|'Taiwan, Taipei'|Z
"Chang's son: Yao-Lu"|55|MAA|'Taiwan, too'|z
```

where sed script could by confined in a little more readable script file as:

```
cat <<oesedscript >csvtopsv.sed 
#!/bin/sed -f 
# Coma Separated Values to Pipe Separated Values
:a
s/^\(\(\(['"]\)[^\3]*\3\|[^",']*\)*\),/\1|/;
ta
oesedscript
chmod +x csvtopsv.sed

./csvtopsv.sed sample
A|B|"C,D"|E|"F|G"|H|"I|J|K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M
A|B|'C,D'|E|'F|G'|H|'I|J|K'
'Chang, Yao-Jen'|33|MIS|'Taiwan, Taipei'|M
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M|'Chang,Yao-Jen'|34|MZZ|'Taiwan, Taipei'|Z
"Chang's son: Yao-Lu"|55|MAA|'Taiwan, too'|z
```

**Explained:**

the `s/` search for quote or double quote `['"]` as third enclosed regex part, followed by 0 or more *other character than mathing third enclosed part*, finaly followed by a second character same as third regex part... OR no coma, single nor double quote `[,'"]`...

**Edit 3** Warn! this was **Wrong!**:

<strike>So right answer seem definitively be something like:</strike>

```
sed -e ':a;s/^\(\(\(['\''"]\)[^\3]*\3\|[^",'\'']*\)*\),/\1|/;ta'
```

you could see my error in adding a `;L` for debugging, before `ta`:

```
sed -e ':a;s/^\(\(\(['\''"]\)[^\3]*\3\|[^",'\'']*\)*\),/\1|/;L;ta'
```

where

```
echo '1,"John Doe","6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55' |
  sed -e ':a;s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|'\''[^'\'']*'\''\|[^",'\'']*\)*\),/\1#/;L;ta'
1#"John Doe","6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1#"John Doe"#"6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1#"John Doe"#"6, rue Peuh"#236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1#"John Doe"#"6, rue Peuh"#236#"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1#"John Doe"#"6, rue Peuh"#236#"B,-,F,H,P,-"#-55
1#"John Doe"#"6, rue Peuh"#236#"B,-,F,H,P,-"#-55
1#"John Doe"#"6, rue Peuh"#236#"B,-,F,H,P,-"#-55
```

we can see that this is not as simple... `[^\3]` dont give intended effect, but instead match for *not char `3`*.

Finaly, we have to search for each delimitor for himself:

```
:a;
s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|'[^']*'\|[^",']*\)*\),/\1\t/;
ta
```

**Nota:** from there, I will present `csv2tsv` as *coma to tab separated values*, if you really prefer to use `|` pipe as separator, you could replace `\t` by `|` or any char you want.

well commmand line is less sexy:

```
echo '1,"John Doe","6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55' |
  sed -e ':a;s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|'\''[^'\'']*'\''\|[^",'\'']*\)*\),/\1\t/;L;ta' 
1       "John Doe","6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1       "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1       "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1       "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236     "B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
1       "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236     "B,-,F,H,P,-"   -55
1       "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236     "B,-,F,H,P,-"   -55
1   "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236     "B,-,F,H,P,-"   -55
```

But this match the need.

```
echo '1,"John Doe","6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55' |
  sed -e ':a;s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|'\''[^'\'']*'\''\|[^",'\'']*\)*\),/\1\t/;ta' 
1       "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236     "B,-,F,H,P,-"   -55
```

In fine, creating ***sedscript***:

```
cat >csv2tsv.sed <<eof
#!/bin/sed -f
# Coma separated values to Tab separated values

:a
s/^\(\("[^"]*"\|'[^']*'\|[^",']*\)*\),/\1\t/;
ta
eof

chmod +x csv2tsv.sed
```

Now:

```
cat >file.csv <<eof
A,B,"C,D",E,"F,G",H,"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen",33,MIS,"Taiwan, Taipei",M
1,"John Doe","6, rue Peuh",236,"B,-,F,H,P,-",-55
4,"hacker's string",'one quote: "I have no special talents. I am only passionat\
ely curious." - Albert Einstein',unquoted string,9,1,1,3
eof

./csv2tsv.sed file.csv 
A   B       "C,D"   E      "F,G"    H    "I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen"    33     MIS      "Taiwan, Taipei"        M
1   "John Doe"      "6, rue Peuh"   236  "B,-,F,H,P,-"      -55
4   "hacker's string"      'one quote: "I have no special talents. I am only pa
ssionately curious." - Albert Einstein' unquoted string 9  1    1       3
```

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley Thanks, but I could do better ;)

Comment: @sputnick there is a new version more efficient

Comment: +1 impressive performance :-)

Comment: But this won't work with quotes like *`"I don't believe in mathematics." - Albert Einstein`*  :-(

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way using `GNU awk` and the [`FPAT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS="|" } $1=$1' file
```

Results:

```
A|B|"C,D"|E|"F,G"|H|"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M
```

Comment: This solution looses empty columns: `A,B,,C,,,D` would produce `A|B|C|D`

Comment: @JamesBrown: Please see the link in my answer. "A straightforward modification (changing the first ‘+’ to ‘*’) allows fields to be empty". Instead use: `awk -v FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS="|" '$NF=$NF' file`

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/,"|",$i)}1' file
A|B|"C,D"|E|"F,G"|H|"I,J,K"
"Chang, Yao-Jen"|33|MIS|"Taiwan, Taipei"|M
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is a learning exercise about sed, I'd use a language with a proper CSV parser, for example:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
    puts CSV.generate_line(CSV.parse_line($_), {:col_sep => "|"})
' filename
```

outputs

```
A|B|C,D|E|F,G|H|I,J,K
Chang, Yao-Jen|33|MIS|Taiwan, Taipei|M
```

The quotes have vanished. That's because there are no "interior" separators that require quoting. If some pipes appear in the input, then you'll see some fields double quoted in the output.

Comment: I see it stripped all the double quotes from the file. Is there an option to leave those alone?

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for your comment. I updated my answer a bit to have the CSV module generate the output line. That way, if there are any separators in the input, they'll be properly quoted in the output.