# Using sed to clean a CSV file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, csv, sed

First of all, I'd like to say that I have searched exhaustively for this solution. It is important that I use `sed` or at least a mix of *nix command line utilities to solve this. I'm dealing with, in some cases, malformed CSV files, but I'm pretty sure it's solvable. I'm missing just one piece of the puzzle.

I'd like to build a converter from CSV to pipe. It should solve the following issues:

1. Strip out `","` and replace with `|`
2. Strip out `",` and replace with `|`
3. Strip out `,"` and replace with `|`
4. Strip out quotes inside quotes
   like: `dog,"john "bud" smith",cat` (becomes `dog|john bud smith|cat`)
5. Strip out `,` which aren't between quotes and replace with `|`

I've completed almost all of this with a `sed` command, but I'm stumped with the commas that are within a field. There is likely a better way but I'm running out of creative thought on the topic. A proper solution will parse this string:

```
1234,"bill","butler","1000,p"r"airie",1234,6789
```

into

```
1234|bill|butler|1000,prairie|1234|6789
```

This is what I have so far:

```
echo '1234,"bill","butler","1000,p"r"airie",1234,6789' |
sed -e 's/","/|/g' -e 's/,"/|/g' -e 's/",/|/g' -e 's/"//g'
```

Comment: how do you distinguish `butler,1000` from `1000,praire`

Comment: You may find http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166454/can-the-csv-format-be-defined-by-a-regex useful and relevant to your question.

Comment: Do you have any correctly formed quotes-within-quotes (`"john ""bud"" smith"`) as documented by [RFC 4180 Comma-Separated Values](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) to deal with?  Do you want those quotes removed?  What, if anything, should be done about pipes that already appear in the input data? Doing this job well is extremely hard.

Comment: @aelor 1000,p"r"airie is technically 1 field. Notice that it's surrounded by ," and ",

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as seen in the example, the field 1000,p"r"airie has 2 extraneous quote that need to be removed and a comma that must remain in place.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler points that the input isn't really standards compliant, you'd probably need an alternate to work with and might not be able to achieve the desired using `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `perl`.  [`Text::Parsewords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) to the rescue:

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -nle 'print join "|", map {s/"//g; $_} parse_line(",",1,$_);' file
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
1234|bill|butler|1000,prairie|1234|6789
```

Comment: That is a nice solution, but hoping to do it all with just sed.

Comment: @BillButler I doubt if you would be able to achieve it with `sed`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                      

l='1234,"bill","butler","1000,p"r"airie",1234,6789'

has_quote_in_quote()
{
    echo $1 | grep -q '[^,]"[^,]'
}

clean_quote_in_quote ()
{
    echo $1 | sed -E -e 's/([^,])"([^,])/\1\2/g'
}

parse()
{
    echo $1 |grep -E -o  '[^"]*|"[^"]*"'
}

pipe_unquoted_commas()
{
    for f in $(parse $1); do echo $f|sed -E -e '/^[^"]/s/,/|/g'; done
}

while has_quote_in_quote $l; do b=$(clean_quote_in_quote $l); l=$b; done

echo $(printf "%s" $(pipe_unquoted_commas $b|sed 's/"//g'))
```

Running this yields

```
1234|bill|butler|1000,prairie|1234|6789
```

It's not obvious to me that this is what you want, but let me explain how it works.

has_quote_in_quote finds any '"' that is not neighboring a comma. clean_quote_in_quote removes all those it can find, but if they are really close, it needs more than one pass due to sed having advanced past the single quoted character in this case -- so whether by chance or deliberate, you example was really well chosen. parse picks either an unquoted or a quoted stretch of text, including the quotes. The "quoted quotes" are removed in the while-loop and then the commas are transformed in the last line, while remaining quotation-characters are removed.

//P

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1234,"bill","butler","1000,p"r"airie",1234,6789' | 
sed -e 's/\([0-9"]\),\([0-9"]\)/\1|\2/g' -e 's/"//g'
```

I defined a rule:

```
, is transformed to the | if it is between numbers or quotes
```

and later just strip out all quotes

EDIT1
Looks like my solution is not working but there is [nice thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475535/replace-every-comma-not-enclosed-in-a-pair-of-double-quotes-with) for this question

Comment: If the string is `1234,"foo77,42bar"` I think the second comma should remain in the output if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right, this script will fail in that case

Comment: Maybe the solution here would be to prepend a comma if the first character is a quote and append a comma if the last character is a quote and then perform the processing. Thoughts? @Girafik

Comment: Unfortunately, it fails in this case: PNPI,ACCTNBR,TRANCD,DESC,SEQ,COMMENT,NT