# Insert `tsv` files into postgresql db

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, insert, csv

I have several files which are saved as tsv. I want to insert them into a `postgresql` db, to analyze them with sql.

However, my problem is how to `INSERT` this tsv files into `postgresql 9.2` under `windows 7`?

I appreciate your reply!

PS.: I have created the table with the right values like:

`CREATE TABLE ratings (distribution VARCHAR, votes VARCHAR, rank FLOAT, title VARCHAR);`

the file is in the directory:

`C:/Users/testUser/Desktop/TSV/ratings.list.tsv`

Comment: tsv as in text search vectors, or did you mean csv as in comma separated values? If the latter, use COPY.

Comment: @Denis Thx for your answer. By tsv I mean as tab seperated values. Could you show an example for how to use COPY in an sql statement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For tab separated values, you can use COPY:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Depending on the exact format of your file, it could be something like:

```
COPY ratings FROM 'C:/Users/testUser/Desktop/TSV/ratings.list.tsv' DELIMITER '\t'
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I immediately tried it, but got: `ERROR: DELIMITER for COPY must be a single one-byte character`

Comment: ok solved it I had to type a tab instead using `\tab`. Thx for your help!

Comment: \t - tab is default, so in this case, you don't need use DELIMITER

Comment: try double-quotes instead of single

Comment: How do you skip the first line since it's a comment?

Comment: I've tried everything mentioned above, but what worked for me was adding `(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER E'\t', HEADER true)` after the 'FROM' clause. Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: What if the .tsv file specifies a value for a `UNIQUE` column which already exists in the table?

Answer (score 37):

You want something like this:

```
COPY ratings FROM 'C:/Users/testUser/Desktop/TSV/ratings.list.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t';
```

The `E'\t'` is required, otherwise you'll get an error like this:

> ERROR: DELIMITER for COPY must be a single one-byte character

---

If the columns in your TSV don't line up perfectly with your table, you can also define the mapping by doing the following:

```
COPY ratings (column_1, column_2, ... column_n)
  FROM 'C:/Users/testUser/Desktop/TSV/ratings.list.tsv'
  DELIMITER E'\t';
```

Comment: if you add CSV to the end, you can also use the HEADER flag

Comment: What if the .tsv file specifies a value for a UNIQUE column which already exists in the table?

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to do this with [csvsql](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/540/scripts/csvsql.html) from [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io).

To read a TSV (or CSV) and create/insert it to a table, my command line script looks like this:

```
csvsql --insert input.tsv  --table table_t --tabs --no-constraints --db postgresql://user:passwd@localhost/mydb
```

Answer (score 0):

Sad to say, but the easiest way is to convert the TSV to a CSV. Most of the built in Postgres import utilities to do things like converting empty strings to nulls, skipping headers, etc are **Only for CSV**.

See this simple [6 line Python answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535255/fastest-way-convert-tab-delimited-file-to-csv-in-linux). I use it and then CSV loaded like normal without a problem in Postgres after trying for and hour to load a TSV.

Comment: Thanks for the download vote. For various use cases the upvoted answer won't work, hence the above suggestion. ;)

Comment: I beg to differ; the default postgresql COPY command defaults to TSV, and I see no difference in support for CSV and TSV. Specifically, both of the commands you mention are present in the configuration for TSV file reading, per this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html