# neo4j import delimiter distinct delimiter for different files

Tags: neo4j

If I have several files that the delimiter between fields are different how i can use the neo4j-import command?
Does I need to convert all the files with the same delimiter between fields?
Thanks in advance 
version 3.1.3

Comment: If you do not use these files in one statement, then you can use the `--delimiter` option: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/command-line-usage/#import-tool-options

Comment: I use in the same command because i want them all in the same graph and

Comment: Documentation says : `All files must use the same delimiter.`

Comment: @sandra Then you need to first bring the files to the same type of separator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535255/fastest-way-convert-tab-delimited-file-to-csv-in-linux